# Using re.sub to remove double quotes

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to remove double quotes from a text file in Python. the statement `print re.sub(r'"', '', line)` works in the interpreter, but not when I use it in a file. Why would this be?

from the interpreter directly:

```
>>> 
>>> import re  
>>> str = "bill"  
>>> print re.sub(r'"', '', str)  
bill
>>>
```

from my .py file:

```
def remove_quotes (filename):  
    with open(filename, 'rU') as file:  
        print re.sub(r'"', '', file.read())
```

output:

```
“Bill”  
“pretty good”       bastante bien  

“friendship”        amistad  
 “teenager”     adolescent
```

OK, as col6y pointed out, I am dealing with fancy L/R quotes. Trying to get rid of them:

```
>>> line  
'\xe2\x80\x9cBill\xe2\x80\x9d\n'  
text = line.replace(u'\xe2\x80\x9c', '')  
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Tried another character encoding:

> > > text = line.replace(u"\u201c", '')
> > >           UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: can you show ur input, expected output and wt you have tried so far??

Comment: Please provide some sample code.

Comment: Why use `re`, and not just a simple built-in `my_string.replace('"', '')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your interpreter example, you say:

```
>>> 
>>> import re  
>>> str = "bill"  
>>> print re.sub(r'"', '', str)  
bill
>>>
```

However, the string `"bill"` does not contain any quotes, so this doesn't test anything. If you try `print str`, you'll see it never had quotes in the first place - this is because the quotes mark that `str` is a string, and are therefore not included. (You wouldn't always want quotes in your strings.) If you wanted to include quotes, you could say `"\"bill\""` or `'"bill"'`.

However, this doesn't explain the real issue in your other program. To understand that, note the difference between `“`, `”`, and `"`. They look similar, but they're slightly different, and are definitely different to the computer. In your file, you have `“` and `”`, but you are replacing the `"`. You'll want to replace the other two as well.

Also, as @MikeT pointed out, it would be easier to use `file.read().replace(...)` instead of `re.replace(..., file.read())`. `re.replace` is for regular expressions, but you don't need their power here.

You should also note that `file.read()` will only read a part of the file, not the whole file. For that, consider using `file.readlines()`, and iterating over the lines.

Comment: good call, colby, you have hit the nail on the head. but how can I get rid of the fancy quotes?

Comment: Just like you got rid of the unfancy ones. (Depending on your editor setup.) `text.replace('“', '').replace('”', '').replace('"', '')` - that will get rid of all three.

Comment: thanks, but I can't type those characters to the interpreter directly or in my text editor (JEdit). My attempts to encode them as unicode have failed, as shown in my post.

Comment: @bill: Have you tried removing the `u` from `.replace(u'\xe2\x80\x9c', '')`? You'd then have `.replace('\xe2\x80\x9c', '')` - this wouldn't parse as unicode, but your input wasn't either, so perhaps it would work anyway?

Comment: thanks, @col6y, that did the trick. I appreciate your assistance.